# How do I generate custom tensorflow training / validation data,

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to classify a bunch of sequences based on the number of occurrences of a particular character.
I'm wanting a network with a 1-dimensional input, so the input (of variable length) can be fed in one character at a time. I then want a floating classification, that's updated after every character is processed.

I'm new to tensforflow, and using the following tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn

A lot of it seems irrelevant as I'm trying to use a completely different dataset.

I've generated my (training/validation 70-30%) data and saved them in a dictionary of the form: `{sequence_string: classification}`.

And I've started investigating the following code for building a model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(2 ** SEQUENCE_MAX_LENGTH, 64),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    TRAINING_DATA, << Doesnt work because my training data format is completely off 
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=TEST_DATA,
    validation_steps=30
)
```

Is this the correct API to be using?
How would I convert my current data to a usable training set?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a sample of your data and target output? (sorry can't comment on posts yet)

You propose to feed in one character at a time and have a prediction that is continuously updated.
There is a problem with this, as recurrent neural networks have a fixed set of weights and therefore have a fixed input size.

You could imitate a 'one character at a time' prediction (perhaps for plotting purposes), by feeding the network a substring of characters. This does mean there is a limit to the number of input characters that are used for a prediction.

**Ex.**
1st prediction: 
[0, 0, 0] -> class A

2nd prediction: 
['T', 0, 0] -> class B

3rd prediction: 
['G', 'T', 0] -> class B

4th prediction: 
['A', 'G', 'T'] -> class C